# Latest stable Docker Desktop Crashes on startup in Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-for-windows

I installed Latest Docker Desktop for Windows in Windows 10 Enterprise. But after installation when I try to start Docker , It presents a crash report as below :

```
Unhandled exception: Sequence contains no elements
   at Docker.Core.Logging.ClientExceptionInterceptor.<InterceptResponseAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\ClientExceptionInterceptor.cs:line 17
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.Logging.LoggingMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\LoggingMessageHandler.cs:line 37
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.BackendAPIClient.<CreateHyperVVMAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\BackendAPIClient.cs:line 93
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.LinuxHyperVEngine.<DoStartAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\LinuxHyperVEngine.cs:line 57
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 36
Original stacktrace:
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<CreateDefaultVMAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 117
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<CreateOrConfigureDockerVMAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 97
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Backend.HyperV.<CreateOrConfigureAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperV.cs:line 130
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Backend.HttpAPI.HyperVAPIController.<CreateVMAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HttpAPI\HyperVAPIController.cs:line 35
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

My Docker version :

```
$docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
```

I have enabled Hyper-V and Containers . Also have a running Ubuntu in WSL

My Windows Version details are :

> 1809 , OS Build-17763.1158

As per the suggestion by @ray, I installed v2.2.0.5. But again crashes with following error :

```
Docker.Core.Backend.BackendDestroyException:

   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.<TrySendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean withNotifications)
   at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<StartAsync>b__0()
   at Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<.ctor>b__1()

  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:

     at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
     at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__97`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     at Docker.Backend.Features.Installer.<>c.<CheckInstalledFeatures>b__1_1(FeatureInfoMap f)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     at Docker.Backend.Features.Installer.CheckInstalledFeatures(Feature[] features)
     at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.CheckInstallation()
     at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
```

Comment: The latest stable docker desktop isn't stable,  you can rollback to v2.2.0.5. [For-win](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues)

Comment: @Ray i have added edit with the crash report after installing v2.2.0.5

Comment: I've been running the Edge version for a long time now, and it's been as stable as the Stable version. It might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Docker Desktop version 3.2.1 isn't stable for windows and has some issues with Docker Desktop Services not working perfectly and that's why after downloading, it crashes. So, the best approach would be to download an older version of the docker desktop [Docker Desktop 2.2.0](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2205).

The Older version works like a charm, I implemented the same.